# Hover background for topmost div?

Tags: html, css

Take a look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/PPsHd/

As expected, hovering over the center div triggers the hover events for all the divs. Is there a way to change the background of only the first div under the hovering mouse? That is, hovering over the center div changes only the center div's color?

edit: This needs to be possible for an arbitrary number of nested divs added by the user and I would be able to do it in javascript, but would prefer a CSS solution.

I'm already using:

```
(function(){
    var highlightedDiv;
    $(document.body).on('mouseover','div',function(e){
        if(highlightedDiv){
            highlightedDiv.style.backgroundColor='';
        }
        (highlightedDiv=this).style.backgroundColor = 'lightGray';
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
)()
```

​

​

Comment: I don't think there is a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're falling foul of event bubbling - I can't see how you'll be able to do it just in CSS -

If you're happy to use a bit of jQuery - you can do it:

```
$("DIV").bind("hover",function(event){
    $(".Hover").removeClass("Hover");
    $(this).addClass("Hover");     
    event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

CSS:

```
div{
    padding-top:50px;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid lightGray;
    background:gray;
}
.Hover{
    background:lightGray;
}
```

The trick is to stop the event bubbling up to the other divs - you [can see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/QNBEe/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest the div's. If you lay them over each other and set the z-index, you can use css for this effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/t9znR/

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I specifically said that this is for an arbitrary and uncontrollable amount of nested elements; specific styles would be impossible.